# The else statement does not execute because if is always true

Tags: linux, perl

To give context to what I am doing this is the assignment: Generate a report containing the lowest, highest and average score for each assignment in the data file. The name of the assignment is located in column 3. Your report should be in a tabular format as shown in the sample below; The input is a csv file with 5 columns: Student, Category, Assignment, Score, and Score Possible.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
@NAMES[0]="first";
my $COUNT=0;
@AVERAGE[0]=0;
@HIGH[0]=0;
@LOW[0]=0;
my $VAL=0;
@SUM[0]=0;
@COUNT_SUM[0]=0;
while(<>){
    chomp;
    @array=split(/,/,$_);

    my $name=@array[2];
    my $score=$array[3];

    if($name=="Assignment"){
        $VAL=1;
    }
    else{ 
        for($i=0;$i<=$COUNT;$i++){
            if($name==$NAMES[$i]){
                $VAL=$i;
                print "it runs\n";
                print $name."\n";
                print $NAMES[$i]."\n";
                $SUM[$i]=$SUM[$i]+$score;
                $COUNT_SUM[$i]++;
                if($name>$HIGH[$i]){
                    $HIGH[$i]=$score;}
                if($name<$LOW[$i]){
                    $LOW[$i]=$score;}
                }
            }

            if($VAL == 0){
                $COUNT++;
                $NAMES[$COUNT] = $name;
                $SUM[$COUNT]=$SUM[$COUNT]+$score;
                $COUNT_SUM[$COUNT]++;
                $LOW[$i]=$score;
                $HIGH[$i]=$score;
            }
            $VAL=0;
        }
        for ($i=1;$i<=$COUNT;$i++){
            $AVERAGE[$i]=$SUM[$i]/$COUNT_SUM[$i];
        }

        print "Name"."\t"."Low"."\t"."High"."\t"."Average\n";
        for ($i=1;$i<=$COUNT;$i++){
            print $NAMES[$i]."\t".$LOW[$i]."\t".$HIGH[$i]."\t".$AVERAGE[$i]."\n"
        }
```

I have tested various things to isolate the problem as it only prints the "Name Low High Average" string without the actual info under it. Somehow, the if statement is always true and the else with the for loop never executes, thus the value of $VAL always equals to 1 and the arrays never get populated.

I know that the code may be inefficient, but I still want to troubleshoot why it does not work.

Comment: You should use `eq` for string comparison, not `==`. Also, you probably want `$array[]` instead of `@array[]` because you want the scalar stored at that array index, not another array. Finally, I recommend adding `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the top of your script to catch issues.

Comment: @craig65535 You are a hero. Thank you brother (or sister). All I needed to do is eq instead of == when comparing the strings. Somehow I missed this in the lecture, or my professor failed to mention it. May someone help you like you helped me today. All the best!

Comment: When setting or accessing a single element of an array, you should use `$` instead of `@`. So `$NAMES[0] = "first", instead of `@NAMES[0] = "first"`. You get this right about 30% of the time, so it's weird that you don't get it right all of the time :-)

Comment: You should add `use strict` and `use warnings` to the top of your code and declare all of your variables (using `my`).

Comment: `for($i=0;$i<=$COUNT;$i++)` is easier to understand if you write it as `for my $i (0 .. $COUNT)`.

Comment: `print "Name"."\t"."Low"."\t"."High"."\t"."Average\n";` can be written as `print "Name\tLow\tHigh\tAverage\n";` and `print $NAMES[$i]."\t".$LOW[$i]."\t".$HIGH[$i]."\t".$AVERAGE[$i]."\n"` can be written `print "$NAMES[$i]\t$LOW[$i]\t$HIGH[$i]\t$AVERAGE[$i]\n"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `eq` instead of `==` for string comparison.

See more references at [Equality Operators section in Perl documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators)